# How can I change the number formatting for my reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-card

I want to know how to change the number format for my reputation like to `1k` instead of 1000 on this site?

I already searched here, but I can't find this out.

Comment: *How to change?*, keep asking and answering, eventually you'll get your `k`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. There is no such user setting.

It will automatically change to have `k` when it is too long (10,000 reputation and over in most places).

Where the display changes to a `k` views depends on the amount of space it is displayed in - so in some places you will see `1k` for 1000.

Comment: Okay leave that , I think 1k means 1000 , But why the SO have 1k means 10000 ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran - 10000 becomes 10k, not 1k. As for deleted comments - I thought I explained - if they add no value and are not about the question/answer, they **should** be deleted, otherwise they are just noise (something that distracts from the focus of the site).

Comment: Okay buddy . It's a poor question ? why somebody give down vote ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran - why ask me? I didn't downvote.

Comment: hmm , okay . I have good answers now , So i will delete this post, bcs some others put down voting . hmm :(

Comment: @RameshRajendran - You can't delete a question that has upvoted answers, as these may be useful to others looking for the same information. Don't get too attached to virtual internet points.

Comment: @RameshRajendran - You seem to talk *too much* via comments. Don't do this. You are adding just noise.

Comment: @Oded But my side , it's a saddest question buddy !!

Comment: @RameshRajendran - When you post on Stack Exchange sites you are actually licensing it as CC-wiki (link in the footer). So, it isn't just yours anymore. And it will not be deleted because with upvoted answers, it may be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

That's not in user settings. It is done by server.

I think its just a part of UI, there might be a width for the user data that is shown under the answer, you can see Oded<>'s answer, he is having 54k, if they were just 54 points (No Offence :D..) he would have only 54 written, where in your case **Let me have the points divided by 1000** would have changed his code to .054k :/ That's stupid! Isn't it?

So you cannot change this on your own. Let server handle them :)

Comment: aaaaaa!!! The Oded say 1k is 10000 points , but You say means 1*1000=1k . Which one is correct ?

Comment: well really `k` means kilo meaning thousand. He said the `k` will appear if points are above `10,000` like this `10k`. `k` means thousand. You can ask him too :)

Comment: oKAY . I FIND IT . AND my questions are get down voted !!!!

Comment: hehe so you think, asking such questions would give you an upvote? You're wrong. Have a look at my profile! :D

Comment: okay okay ! any way , i don't want points, bcs i accept the down vote for  wrong or silly question  . So i asked that , any way thanks for your post !

Comment: welcome :) and its good to just answer what you feel and downvote what you think is stupid! (y)